# Keeping controls in landscape mode but allowing uitabbar to switch

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitabbar, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a UITabBar switches places when the iphone changes orientation and that works fine, but I want the controls within the view of the first tab to stay static regardless of the position of the phone. 
I feel like I'm missing something obvious?

Edit:
Basically, the controls are always landscape but the tab bar must switch orientations. It this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the view in which you don't want the controls to readjust, disable the autoresizing: `[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];`. This will prevent all controls (subviews) from responding to interface orientation changes and yet the tab will still respond. You might also have to set the autoresizingMask of the current view: `[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];`

**Addition : try the following for all controls you don't want to rotate**

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
   switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
      case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
         label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); // 90 degress
         break;
      case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
         label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI + M_PI_2); // 270 degrees
         break;
      case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
         label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); // 180 degrees
         break;
      default:
         label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm adding this in the viewDidLoad of the view that I don't wat to switch but the controls are still moving...should i do it somewhere else?

Comment: Weird. Does your app start up in landscape mode?

Comment: it actually does if I have the "Supported interface orientation" key in the info.plist to be landscape, but even if i remove it and the app starts portrait. The view controls move

Comment: ugh man so close...when I rotate it with the home button to the right there is background image that shifts to the left and leaves a blank gap. 
I'm actually replacing label.transform with self.view.transform

Comment: That's probably the backgroundView, you might have to prevent it rotating as well (using `self.view.transform = ...;`)

Comment: I replaced the label.transform for self.view.transform and don't do it to anything else...and here are two pics of what happens
Here is in  [portrait](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y27/irco/Screenshot2011-05-01at41407PM.png) and here is what happens in [landscape](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y27/irco/Screenshot2011-05-01at41417PM.png)
(sorry about the stupid blur..i signed an NDA)

Comment: I guess the view in the background is just too small on creation of the main view. You probably have to increase the size of the frame on initialization.

Comment: It actually makes sense..I have a tab bar to its 'left' when it's on portrait and when it goes to landscape the tab moves down and leaves the gap. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

example of Landscape

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

OR

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

Comment: I understand that, and that;s what im doing so that the tabbar at the bottom reacts to the switching of orientation, but I want to keep the controls within the view from moving but not the tabbar

Comment: setOrientation is private API and shouldn't be used, also stopped working in I think it was IOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not exactly straightforward. You can't have the UITabBarController respond to interface changes while not having the content view controller respond.

But there is a way to do it. In the content view controller's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, you can apply an opposite rotation (using the `transform` property) to the subviews that you don't want rotated. For example,  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft is a 90° clockwise rotation, so if you apply a 90° counterclockwise rotation to the view's `transform` it will seem to not have rotated.

If you want, you could include the entire interface of the content view controller in a UIView so you just have to counterrotate (and possibly resize) that one view. I don't know whether it would work to apply the counterrotation on the view controller's main view, the system may override your setting for that particular view.

Comment: this is my first time doing anything like this...I'm trying to rotate it like this


     CGAffineTransform transform = self.view.transform;
     transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -(M_PI / 2.0));
     self.view.transform = transform;

But there is bkgnd image that moves down and to the right..im not sure why

Comment: @irco: I see you posted pictures in another comment above. It looks like you aren't taking into account the fact that the area for the content view in portrait is probably something like 320x416, while in landscape it's probably (after counteracting the rotation) something like 268x480. Also, BTW, you can use the constant `M_PI_2` instead of `M_PI / 2.0`, although the compiler will probably generate identical code modulo possible inaccuracy in the last digit.